# Where to create repository instances?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, python, clean-code

I've several repositories. To make them testable, I add the ORM session in the constructor.

```
class Repository:
  def __init__(session):
    self.session = session

  def save(object):
    self.session().query(object).save()

class FruitRepository(Repository):
  def custom_method():
   # ...
   pass
```

**Problem**: I need to inject the session every time I instantiate a repository. I'd like to have only one place in my code where the injection happens.

To clean things up I'd like to separate creation from usage:

```
from db import session

def create_fruit_repository():
  return FruitRepository(session)

repository = create_fruit_repository()
```

It doesn't feel clean. Does anyone know a proper pattern to solve this issue? Maybe the factory pattern?

**Edit**
Further information: the application is a web scraper with several layers (loading, processing, analysing, reporting). It has some dependencies, but no framework. The application runs constantly as a services, not as a cronjob. Most is done on the command line, but it provides a REST-API.

Comment: Can you explain more about the program you are trying to create? The overall architecture of the application makes a big difference.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks for your reply. It's a more or less complex web scraper with several layers. It loads, processes, analyses and reports. Unfortunately I can't rely on an existing framework.

Comment: This is good information. Please [edit] your question instead of commenting. It is too easy to miss this in comments. As for the web scraper, is this just a Python script started from a cron job or command line?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks, I just edited the question including the answer to your latest question.

Comment: @Mr.B. are you familiar with the concept of  "Composition Root"? If not, Mark Seemann [little introduction](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) might be a good starting point for you, Special attention to the last paragraph.

Comment: @Laiv I didn't know the term. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Have you considered using a scraping framework such as Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

CLI or API both are likely to have an entry point. The so-called `Main` or `Application`.

Sometimes, it's a class and sometimes is a function. In some programming languages is a mix of both. In any case, this entry point is the best place for your *Composition Root*. It's the epicentre of your dependency graph explosion. Where you instantiate everything and pass it downstream.

CLI apps are kinda *fire and forget* executables. The `Main` builds a new graph every time. Dependencies are created and passed downstream up to the end of the execution path. Then, the execution and the `Main` end.

Endless loops applications are a bit different. The *Composition Root* is not enough. It builds the graph once and it must be accessible and executable anytime (for efficiency). It's then when we need a place to store (in memory) the graph and a way to access it. The link I shared (see comments above) mentions the *Service Registry pattern*. Frameworks might have other names: ApplictionContext, Container, etc...

Comment: An alternative to the service registry is to use factories. This enables parts of the graph to be lazily constructed on demand, potentially when needed, whilst still keeping the construction code in the composition root.